# how to make register battery Broadcast work in Manifest instead of in an Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, batterymanager

I am trying to get actions performed on battery change. For that I have used the following code:

```
public class BatteryBroadcastReceiver extends 
BroadcastReceiver {

DatabaseHelper db;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
String cont1 = db.usercontact().toString();

String action = intent.getAction();
if (action != null && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)) {

    int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,-1);
    int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE,-1);
    int percentage = level * 100 / scale;

    if(percentage <=  20){
       // doing something like getting location
    }
}
}
```

I have registered my broadcast in my activity:

```
public class Battery extends AppCompatActivity {

  private BatteryBroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BatteryBroadcastReceiver();
  private IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_location);

 }

@Override
protected void onResume(){
super.onResume();
registerReceiver(batteryReceiver,intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
unregisterReceiver(batteryReceiver);
super.onPause();
}
```

This general piece of code is working fine but it is restricting me to just this activity (may be because broadcast is registered in this activity). Like as long as this activity remains open I can perform some task but as I closes it, when battery gets low it perform no task. Now I don't know what to do. I have other activities too in my application and I want it to work even when I am not on this activity. Is there any way that I can register it in manifest so that it could work overall. I have tried doing that but then nothing happens on battery change. Thanks for help in advance :).

Comment: Can anyone answer me here.

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer possible to register for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` in the manifest. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED

If you want to get triggered by this broadcast `Intent` in all of your activities, you can do this one of 2 ways:

- Register and unregister the receiver in each and every one of your activities. You could simplify this by creating a `BaseActivity` that handles the register and unregister of the `BroadcastReceiver` and then extending all your activities from `BaseActivity`.
- Register the receiver when your app starts in a custom `Application` class, or in `onCreate()` of your first `Activity`. Don't unregister the receiver. This causes a small memory leak, but I wouldn't worry about it.